# In Play Framework 2.3, how do I configure and apply evolutions to the in-memory database?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, specs2, slick-2.0, play-slick

With my Play 2.3.8/Slick 2.1 app, I'm trying to figure out how to set up multiple databases in my application.conf (MySQL and an in-memory database in MySQL mode), with one being automatically used for testing.  I think I got close, but it gives me this error:

```
 InconsistentDatabase: : Database 'test' is in an inconsistent state![An evolution has not been applied properly. Please check the problem and resolve it manually before marking it as resolved.]  (Evolutions.scala:196)
```

I see a lot of related questions/documentation out there, but it either is out of date, or not exactly matching what I'm trying to do.

Here's what I have in my application.conf

```
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/maindb"
db.default.user="admin"
db.default.password="test"

applyEvolutions.default=true

db.test.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.test.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL"
db.test.user=sa
db.test.password=""

applyEvolutions.test=true

slick.default= "models.database.*"
slick.test= "models.database.*"
```

I realized, for this to work, I probably need to duplicate my evolution scripts into a conf/evolutions/test directory, so I did that.  I also wonder if I can just symlink it, to avoid needing to maintain two copies.

Here's one of my Spec2 tests:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._
import org.junit.runner._
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import org.specs2.execute.{Result, AsResult}
import play.api.db.slick._
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._
import models.database.OwnersDatabase._

abstract class WithDbData extends WithApplication(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase("test"))) {
  override def around[T: AsResult](callback: => T): Result = super.around {
    prepareDbWithData()
    callback
  }

  def prepareDbWithData() = DB("test").withSession {
    implicit session => owners ++= TestData.inputData
  }
}

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class OwnerControllerSpec extends Specification {

  "OwnerController" should {    

    "on owners return list of owners" in new WithDbData {
      val result = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/owners")).get

      status(result) must equalTo(OK)
      contentType(result) must beSome("application/json")
      contentAsJson(result) mustEqual TestData.expectedOwnersAll
    }

  }
}
```

And here's the TestData class used to populate the table:

```
import models.Owner
import play.api.libs.json._

object TestData {
  val inputData = Seq(
    Owner("sam", "password", Some("Sam"), "test@example.com", None, "90210"),
    Owner("herb", "password", Some("Herb"), "test@example.com", None, "90210")
  )

  val expectedOwnersAll = Json.obj(
    "rows" -> JsArray(Seq(
      Json.obj("username" -> "sam", "password" -> "password", "name" -> "Sam", "email" -> "test@example.com", "pic_id" -> "", "zipcode" -> "90210"),
      Json.obj("username" -> "herb", "password" -> "password", "name" -> "Herb", "email" -> "test@example.com", "pic_id" -> "", "zipcode" -> "90210")
    ))
  )
}
```

What's going wrong?  And am I doing anything that's considered bad practice?

Comment: what about the ebean server where you point to the models. `ebean.default="models.*"`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that line... I have the line `slick.default= "models.database.*"` in my application.conf file.